# Jquery string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I might be overlooking the obvious but I am trying to do a basic string concatenation and it does not seem to play to well

I have the following variables

```
var plug = "myPlug";
var pdiv = "<p></p>";
var tab_id = "#someID";

$(tab_id + "p:contains('" + plug + "')").parent().next().append(pdiv);
```

For some reason `tab_id` does not get substituted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you want a space before the "p" in "p:contains(...)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leave a space between `#someID` and `p:contains`. Concatenation does not add spaces by itself.

You need to use:

```
$(tab_id + " p:contains('" + plug + "')").parent().next().append(pdiv);
            ^
          give extra space here
```

Answer (score 2):

because you are looking for

```
("#someIDp:contains....")
        ^^
      No space
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a space.  Currently your selector will evaluate to:

```
$("#someIDp:contains('myPlug')")
```

which... doesn't look right.  Try adding a space after the ID and before the child `p` element:

```
$(tab_id + " p:contains('" + plug + "')")
```